# How to git-log all branches that contain a specific commit

Tags: git, git-branch, git-log

`git log` accepts multiple branch names as parameters, and using `--graph` you get a nice tree-view of it. With `--all` I see the complete tree, with `--branches` I can even filter branch names.

I want to show the complete history of all (sub)branches of a specific branch. To that end, I want to know **how can I `git log` all branches that contain some commit?**

*With `git branch --contains`, I can find all branches that contain a specific commit. So with some bash-wizardry, I could probably make up a command that does what I want. But I'm guessing that git should have a more direct way to get such a log.*

Comment: Git's one tool in a toolkit.  `git log --graph $(git branch --contains $thatcommit|sed s/.//)` couldn't be much simpler.